# Count the no of occurence of a each string and print the eac number and string side by side using python

Tags: python-3.x

## USING PYTHON3

So this is my question, say I have a string

```
my_str="aaaaabbbbcccdde"
```

I want to write a code that gives me an output as

```
5a4b3c2d1e
```

I saw a code in the book automate the boring stuff that does something similar but not exactly.

This is the code below:

```
my_str="aaaaabbbbcccdde"
count = {}
for character in my_str:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character]+= 1
print(count)
for item in count:
    print(count[item], item)
```

and this is the output it gives me:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1}
5 a
4 b
3 c
2 d
1 e
```

not

**5a4b3c2d1e**

which is the output I want.

Help anyone? (:

Comment: Can you have non-consecutive repetition, if so how would you treat them e.g. "aaabbccca"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this brother by modifying your own code's output. Happy coding!

```
my_str="aaaaabbbbcccdde"
    count = {}
    for character in my_str:
        count.setdefault(character, 0)
        count[character]+= 1
    string_to_print = ""
    for item in count:
        string_to_print += str(count[item])+item
    print(string_to_print)
```

Output:

```
5a3c4b1e2d
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked. The last line should be not be indented though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
count = {}
for char in my_str:
    count[char] = count.get(char,0) + 1
for item in count:
    print(count[item],item,sep='', end='')

5a4b3c2d1e
```

if you need a one liner, you could do:

```
''.join([str(my_str.count(i)) + i for i in sorted(set(my_str),key = my_str.index)])
Out: '5a4b3c2d1e'
```

Comment: Thanks for this one liner really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re`:

```py
import re

my_str="aaaaabbbbcccdde"

res=eval(re.sub(r"(.)(\1*)", r"+str(len('\2\1'))+'\1'", my_str)[1:])
```

Output:

```py
5a4b3c2d1e
```

**Caveat**

It aggregates consecutive chars only i.e.

```py
import re

my_str="aaaaabbbbcccddea"

res=eval(re.sub(r"(.)(\1*)", r"+str(len('\2\1'))+'\1'", my_str)[1:])

#outputs:
>> 5a4b3c2d1e1a
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. All you need to do to complete the code is to concat `count[item]` and `item` together and add it to the list. Then join all list elements into a final string.

```
my_str = "aaaaabbbbcccdde"
count = {}
list_1 = []
for character in my_str:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] += 1
print(count)
for item in count:
    new_item = str(count[item]) + item
    list_1.append(new_item)

final_string = ''.join(list_1)
print(final_string)
```

Output

```
5a4b3c2d1e
```

Or if you don't want to make another list you can just make an empty string variable and concat to that directly

```
my_str = "aaaaabbbbcccdde"
final_string = ""
count = {}
for character in my_str:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] += 1
print(count)
for item in count:
    final_string += str(count[item]) + item

print(final_string)
```

Output

```
5a4b3c2d1e
```